# Correct character for writing dimensions in HTML

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics

When I'm writing dimensions in HTML, what is the correct, semantic way to write them so that screen readers and other assistive technologies will interpret them correctly?

For example, I'm talking about physical dimensions of a building on a page, I want to write something along the lines of "*the building is 100x200 feet in size*". For this, I can use a regular lower-case **`x`**, **`&times;`** or **`&#10005;`**. Beyond these, there are several other similar characters to choose from, but I don't know which is best.

Any suggestions or input would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this question is a better fit for [ux.se]? I don't know though, just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is also a problem of text-alternative. How do you pronounce it?

- *the building is 100* **by** *200 feet in size*

If so, then you should chose between using the full form, or using a text-replacement:

- the building is 100`<span aria-label="by">x</span>`200 feet in size

No matter which char you use, the most important thing is to have something understandable by screen readers (and sighted users of course)

Comment: so perhaps a combination of the two? `<span aria-label="by">&times;</span>` seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes, `×` is more understandable than `x` or `*`

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google search of "area" the top result I got was [maths is fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/area.html). They use × (&times;) Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area) uses it too, I think &times; is a safe bet.

Comment: I tried reading the `&times;` character with both NVDA and JAWs in IE, Firefox and Chrome and both screen readers either skip it or say the character 'x'.